# MCU-signals to VGA conversion

Tags: vga

I have a board that produces MCU-signals for a display to render.
The chip is a [65510 (datasheet)](http://vgamuseum.info/images/doc/chips/f65510.pdf) which is configured to generate signals according to page 128 (Monochrome, single drive, 2pixels/clock). The pixel clock runs at 12.5Mhz.

My goal is to convert the signals into an 640 × 480 VGA signal.
I tried doing the conversion with a teensy 4.1 but concluded it is to slow to capture the MCU signals and put the data into a buffer.

It should be doable with an FPGA, unfortunately I am not familiar with Verilog/VHDL.

Are there any premade boards which perform this conversion? I couldn't find any though I would guess they would exist.